# I've tried installing ubuntu to my mac with rEFIT but it doesnt boot up with it and I dont have the "Install ubuntu alongside osx" button

Tags: dual-boot, software-installation, mac, macosx, refit

I'm trying to install ubuntu alongside with my mac for hours please help me it doesnt boot up with my mac and when I boot it with ubuntu disk (from holding c while its still booting up) I dont have the install alongside with osx button please help me

Answer (score 0):

@Burak

I also had considerable difficulty getting ubuntu to install for different reasons (first of which I am running OS X 10.7, Lion), however I did succeed in getting the amd64 image to install 'alongside'.

There are a few things that are inconsistent with your post.

First thing, is rEFIt is the older (non-supported EFI loader). You need to use rEFInd (rodsbooks.com/refind), especially if you are trying to make a dual boot on Yosemite or Maverick or any number of cat names back to v10.4

The second issue, I had with 10.7 was the instructions to convert the ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso into a dmg on a USB stick for rEFInd to load.

I first did this using the [ubuntu instructions for building dmg on USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx).

The only caveat to the above being that you should use 'unmountDisk' and target /dev/disk'N's1 where 'N' is the number of the device. At last success but no dice with rEFInd. When I booted into any of the bootloaders (oh yea, 3 of which were visible). One of which gave me the error: "No boot device" and two of which took me to the backup grub bootloader. If I chose 'Install ubuntu' I would hear the drums for ubuntu start (as if the OS had loaded), but I would not see anything load at all.

I then tried the same process with the ubuntu-desktop-i386.iso (the 32bit version). **Note:** I was at first confused because I know my mac has an Intel i7, that was 64bit... but it turns out that there's a long history as to why ubuntu chose 'amd64' as the name for the 64bit version... in any case, no dice with the i386 dmg either and rEFInd.

Then I tried using the really handy tool UNetbootin (unetbootin.sourceforge.net) - thinking maybe I was doing something wrong in building the dmg? But apparently not.

At this point I was getting discouraged. But I thought, well, let's try the old fashioned way. So, I dusted off a 4.7G dvd and burned the ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso to disk and then I restarted. Again no dice with rEFInd... but alas! there is a solution.

If you leave the dvd in the drive and boot while holding the 'alt/option' key. You will get another boot menu (one that's stock to mac). You should see your HD, your Recovery HD, and probably two CDs (one that says 'WINDOWS' and one that says 'EFI boot'). In my case if I choose the EFI boot, it will behave the same way as it did in the rEFInd description above.

However, if you choose the 'WINDOWS' cd (contrary to popular belief) it will probably load ubuntu desktop right off the disk and you will be able to choose 'Install Alongside Mac OS X' in about the third or forth option into the install.

Be sure that you followed the instructions for making space with Disk Utility before you attempt to install from the CD. Just leave the space unallocated, and don't make a partition for ubuntu - let 'alongside' option do the work. A fairly good overview of this [partition process is here](http://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/).